# i want to get the value of selected index in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

i want to get the value of selected  index in gridview in but i am not get the value please tell how  i am not know in which event of grid i get the value
i use this code on onselectedindexchange event of grid and on rowediting

but how i get the value i am not know

Code is

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;   
}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    string s = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[6].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "CellContentClick" function for grid to get Index

```
private void GridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int columnIndex=Convert.ToInt(e.ColumnIndex.ToString());
    int rowIndex=Convert.ToInt(e.RowIndex.ToString());
}
```

I have gone for DataGrid and find "SelectedIndex" function it will give the index of selected cell or return (-1) in no cell is selected.

Here is the link for the same:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: this is for datagrid view.For grid this  is not work.

Comment: sir please give the idea for gridview